# tkinter and image. Making an image fit into label

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter

I got some trouble properly making an image fit to my label.
I use selenium to go to a website and take a picture, I then want to display this picture in my label.

It successfully takes the picture and shows it, but it's dimensions is all messed up. I'd like for the picture to keep it's original size but gets zoomed out to make it fit within the frame.

Are there any way to accomplish this to make it look properly?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
from _tkinter import create

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Rasmus\Desktop\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe')
driver.get('http://www.mtggoldfish.com/metagame/modern#online')

driver.find_element_by_class_name

driver.save_screenshot('screeniess.png')
driver.close()

class App(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.frameBilled = Frame(self.frame, background="#c0c0c0", width=600, height= 350)
        self.frameBilled.pack()

        im_temp = Image.open("screeniess.png")
        im_temp = im_temp.resize((600, 350), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        im_temp.save("ArtWrk.ppm", "ppm")
        self.photo = PhotoImage(file="artwrk.ppm")
        self.labelBilled = Label(self.frameBilled, image=self.photo)
        self.labelBilled.photo = self.photo 
        self.labelBilled.pack() 

root = Tk()
root.title("Application")
root.geometry("600x800")
root.resizable(0,0)
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

edit: I think it may be Selenium not taking a fullpage screenshot. If I manually insert a picture into my label it'll fit properly.

Comment: It works just exactly as your source code says on my computer. If you want to keep the original size of the image, then you should not resize it.

Answer (score 1):

Had to use driver.maximize_window()